# Concatenating strings / rows using dplyr, group_by with mutate() or summarize() & str_c() or paste() & collapse, but maintain NA & all strings

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, concatenation, na

When concatenating strings using `dplyr`, `group_by()` and `mutate()` or `summarize ()` with `paste()` and `collapse`, `NA` values are coerced to a string `"NA"`.

When using `str_c()` instead of `paste()`, strings that are concatenated with `NA` are removed (`?str_c`: *whenever a missing value is combined with another string the result will always be missing*). When having such combinations of `NA` & non-`NA` values, how can I remove the `NA` instead of the non-`NA` in the concatenation?

See my example below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4)
string <- c(' asfdas ', 'sdf', NA,'sadf', 'NA', NA)
df <- data.frame(ID, string)
#   ID   string
# 1  1  asfdas 
# 2  1      sdf
# 3  2     <NA> # ID 2 has both NA and non-NA values
# 4  2     sadf #
# 5  3       NA
# 6  4     <NA>
```

Both,

```
df%>%
 group_by(ID)%>%
 summarize(string = paste(string, collapse = "; "))%>%
 distinct_all()
```

and

```
df_conca <-df%>%
 group_by(ID)%>%
 dplyr::mutate(string = paste(string, collapse = "; "))%>%
 distinct_all()
```

result in

```
     ID string               
1     1 " asfdas ; sdf"
2     2 "NA; sadf"           
3     3 "NA"
4     4 "NA" # NA coerced to "NA"
```

I.e. `NA` becomes "NA":

while

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  summarize(string = str_c(string, collapse = "; "))
```

results in:

```
     ID string               
1     1 " asfdas ; sdf"
2     2 NA     
3     3 "NA" 
4     4 NA
```

I.e. "sadf" is removed according to the `str_c` rule: `NA` combined with string, results in `NA`.

However, I would like to keep the true `NA` values (in e.g. 'ID' 4) and the strings only (in e.g. 'ID' 2), as such:

```
     ID string             
1     1 " asfdas ; sdf"
2     2 "sadf"           
3     3 "NA"
4     4 NA
```

Ideally, I would like to stay within the `dplyr` workflow.

---

This question is an extension of [Concatenating strings / rows using dplyr, group_by & collapse or summarize, but maintain NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69301805/concatenating-strings-rows-using-dplyr-group-by-collapse-or-summarize-but)

Comment: Maybe `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(str_c(if(any(!is.na(string))) na.omit(string) else string, collapse = ","))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pivot_wider` and `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   mutate(rn = rowid(ID)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = string) %>% 
   unite(string, `1`, `2`, na.rm = TRUE, sep = " ; ")%>%
   mutate(string = na_if(string, ""))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ID string          
  <dbl> <chr>           
1     1 " asfdas  ; sdf"
2     2 "sadf"          
3     3 "NA"            
4     4  <NA>
```

---

Or may also use `coalesce`

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(string = na_if(coalesce(str_c(string, collapse = " ; "),
     str_c(string[complete.cases(string)], collapse = " ; ")), ""))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ID string          
  <dbl> <chr>           
1     1 " asfdas  ; sdf"
2     2 "sadf"          
3     3 "NA"            
4     4  <NA>
```

Comment: The second solution requires 1/10 of the processing time as compared to the first solution. It is also less code intense.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in the dplyr framework.
This removes all the 'NA' values using filter() - which initially loses ID 4 - then replaces the missing ID using a join.

```
df_IDs <- data.frame(ID = unique(df$ID))
df%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  filter(!is.na(string)) %>%
  summarize(string = paste(string, collapse = "; ")) %>%
  full_join(df_IDs, by = "ID")
```

results in

```
     ID string                  
1     1 " asfdas ; sdf"
2     2 "sadf"         
3     3 "NA"           
4     4  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

So what is the best answer to be granted the accepted answer endorsement?

I enlarged the sample data and ran a short benchmark.

```
ID <- sample(1:4, 1000000, replace = T)
string <-  sample(c(' asfdas ', 'sdf', NA,'sadf', 'NA', NA), 1000000, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(ID, string)
```

An the winner is arkun's second answer. Shortest code and shortest processing time. However, the processing time differs only by milliseconds (besides arkun's first answer, which takes tenfold).

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(string = na_if(coalesce(str_c(string, collapse = " ; "),
     str_c(string[complete.cases(string)], collapse = " ; ")), ""))
```

Anyhow, I guess it should be possible accepting multiple answers within stack exchange, as different answers might work best in different circumstances.

Besides, the behavior of `dplyr::mutate(string = paste(string, collapse = "; "))` seems quite unexpected to me and would be worth to be changed with some dplyr update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your efforts, I came up with my own answer in the meanwhile:

```
 replace(is.na(.),'XXX_MY_NAs_XXXX')%>%
 group_by(ID)%>%
 summarize(string = paste(string, collapse = "; "))%>%
 dplyr::mutate_all(funs(str_replace_all(., c('XXX_MY_NAs_XXXX; ' = ''
                                          ,'; XXX_MY_NAs_XXXX' = ''))))%>%
 na_if(., 'XXX_MY_NAs_XXXX')
```